# Error trying to use %ROWTYPE to table in a different schema in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write an Oracle PL/SQL function similar to 

`create or replace function fn1(p_id in number) return number is
  crec otheruser.thetable%rowtype;
begin
 ...
end;`

but I get an error saying "Identifier 'OTHERUSER.THEABLE' must be declared".  This same construct works fine if I login as otheruser.  I'm able to `select * from otheruser.thetable` so it seems to me that my account can see the table just fine.  I'm thinking it's a grant issue but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: otheruser needs to give you read grant.

Comment: Are your permissions on the other user's table granted via a role, rather than directly to you?

Comment: The grant is through a role.  Didn't think that would make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either use:

```
GRANT SELECT ON OtherUser.TheTable TO ThisUser;
```

Then you can use `ROWTYPE` directly in `ThisUser` session:

```
DECLARE
  a_row OtherUser.TheTable%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

But the `ThisUser` will also be able to select all the data from `OtherUser.TheTable`.

Or, if you do not want to grant the `SELECT` privilege you can create a package and grant on that:

```
CREATE PACKAGE OtherUser.TheTable_Pkg
AS
  SUBTYPE TheTable_RowType IS OtherUser.TheTable%ROWTYPE;
END;
/

GRANT EXECUTE ON OtherUser.TheTable_Pkg TO ThisUser;
```

Then you can do, as `ThisUser`:

```
DECLARE
  a_row OtherUser.TheTable_Pkg.TheTable_RowType;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

And the type can be used but the data in the table is still inaccessible.

Comment: I have select on the table, but as I responded to the comment above it is through a role.  Should that make a difference?

Comment: Yes it does. While you can get the necessary grants through a role the compiler cannot.  If the object being referenced (table, view, type,etc) is not owned by the same schema as the object being compiled then a direct grant to the foreign object is required.

Comment: @Belayer In 12c both `GRANT SELECT OtherUser.TheTable TO ARole` and `GRANT EXECUTE ON OtherUser.TheTable_Pkg To ARole` and then `GRANT ARole to ThisUser` appear to allow the type to be used.

Comment: Granting direct to the user works as expected.  I tested it in our development environment.  Unfortunately, the solution is not acceptable for our production environment so I'm having to look for a different approach but I'm accepting it for any future browsers.

Comment: @Belayer thanks for the note on grants through a role.